# How parsing this Json streaming Python3.4

Tags: php, json, streaming, python-3.4

**How to parse this API JSON streaming from PHP server with Python3.4?**

```
    import requests
    import json

    url = 'http://api.example.com'
    parameters = {'code':1, 'user': 'default', 'password': 'default'}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

    response = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(parameters), headers=headers)
    text = response.text
    data = json.loads(text)
    print (json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

**Output :**

```
{
    "streaming": {
        "1": {
            "product": "01",
            "progress": "SUCCESS",
            "proces": "IMPORT",
            "datetime": "2015-11-23 00-00-00",
            "user": "David"
        },
        "10": {
            "product": "02",
            "progress": "succes",
            "proces": "Sending email",
            "datetime": "2015-11-23 00-00-01",
            "user": "David"
        }}}
```

**I tried to filter the dictionary but i cant, because dicts with non-strings as keys and i got error.**

Answer (score 1):

use `json_decode()` to parse your json object.

```
$json = "your content"
$decoded = json_decode($json);

print_r($decoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

**json_decode()** is utilized to decode json string into either an **associative array** or **php standard object** dependent upon value of **boolean argument $assoc**.

Following is code snippet for parsing json content in php

```
  $json_string='{
    "code": 1,
    "user": "default",
    "password": "default"
}';
     $json_array=json_decode($json_string,true);
```

For detailed description regarding parsing **json content** in php please refer the documentation of **json_decode** function mentioned in following 
URL.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php